# Confuse about responsive image use cases

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

In the [Responsive Use Case](http://usecases.responsiveimages.org/#h2_use-cases), I confused about the **Resolution-based selection** and **Viewport-based selection**. I think they are the same.

I think they are both talking about choosing the appropriate size image for the specify screen size. If big size image apply to small mobile device, bandwidth and performance will be wasted.

Am I right? If I'm wrong, what exactly the differences between **Resolution-based selection** and **Viewport-based selection**?

Comment: viewport is like scaling your browser to different sizes, and depending on that size the viewport based image is selected (i.e. from fixed width to 100% width) - resolution is, if you are looking at the result on a retina display, your viewport will have same size, but pixel depth is twice the size, so actually using images in twice the resolution give same output with better image result on retina displays

Comment: @hexereisoftware : I think the the situation you talk about *pixel depth*, should be refer to the **Device-pixel-ratio-based selection**

Comment: i appologize, yes, i was referring to section 3.3. but now i see the difference. the first is selecting image according to screen-size, the second the viewport depends on your layout. so on large screens you might have 4 images next to each other, on middle screens 2, etc. as shown in the image, so there the image size would not depend on the screen resolution, but on the container size that it is placed in